# why the jquery click event is working in plunker but not in any of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am making a UI in which jquery click event is used.It is working in plunker but not in any of the browser can someone please tell me why
my plunker link is [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gkjWUnMUyER6dAbTcfms)

and my code for jquery is

```js
var s="<span class='" + id + "'style='border: 1px Solid Black;position:absolute;height:25px;left:" + left1 + "px;background-color:" + color11 + ";width:" + k + "px'>" + name + "<div class='tooltip'><table id='jumble'><tbody><tr><th>Resource Type</th><th>Resource Category</th><th>Resources</th><th>Skills</th></tr> <tr><td>types</td><td>category</td><td>count</td><td>skills</td></tr></tbody></table></div></span>";
```

```js
$('span').click(function(){
    $(this).closest("span").find(".tooltip").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: could you post an html fragment?

Comment: i have added it above

Comment: @deepak just a pointer. You should not have multiple `$(document).ready()` functions. Also are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: thanks for pointing that and i am not getting any errors.

Comment: Try using `console.log()` in click event and check if event is getting called or not.

Comment: When you add elements dynamically, events bindings does not work and you will have to use event delegates

Comment: thanks i was having problem because i was calling clicking event from another js file now its sorted if i use in same code. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html I only saw one span so why don't you use something like this:

```
$('span').click(function(){
    $(this).find(".tooltip").toggle("slow");
});
```

If you have several clickabble span in you dom you can use:

```
$('span').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).find(".tooltip").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `$(document).ready()` function twice in your scripts.That is causing the issue.

Thanks

Comment: i deleted it but still no luck i updated the code in plunker too

Comment: no i was not getting any error before and after deleting document.ready

Comment: Using document.ready more than once does not prevent scripts from executing. This is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code it's not clear if you are appending the **span html element** via javascript or not.

By the way, if you append the element after the "DOMContentLoaded" event (aka jQuery Document Ready) you are not able to register any event listener on it, so, you probably need to use a delegate event which is explained at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Have a look on this example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var container = $('#container');
  var newElement = $('<span />', {
    text: "click on me"
  });
  
  
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    container.append(newElement);
  }, 2000);
  
  var counter = 0;
  container.delegate('span', 'click', function(event) {
    counter += 1;
    
    $('#counter').text(counter);
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
#container 
{ 
    padding: 1em .5em; 
    background: lightseagreen; 
}

#container span 
{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    padding: 1em .5em; 
    background: lightcoral; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you are adding the span control dynamically to your page. You can not use the .click() event binder for the dynamically generated control.

To make this work use the .on() as shown below

```
$('body').on('click','span',function(){
    $(this).closest("span").find(".tooltip").toggle("slow");
});
```